# How To Share Same UIView Between Multiple UITableView Cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

**Objective**

> When the user clicks on any of the 3 blue buttons, all buttons change to the same color.

Note: this is an abstraction of a shared progress view problem, it's therefore important that only one UIView is shared (or mimicked) across my three rows

Here is a compilable Swift project:

```
import UIKit

class ToggleButton: UIButton {
    var connectedView: UIView?
    func onPress() {
        self.isHidden = true
        self.connectedView?.isHidden = false
    }
}

class ViewController : UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    var tableView: UITableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 300))

    var myView: UIView? = nil
    var toggleBtn: ToggleButton? = nil

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        self.setupTableView()
    }

    fileprivate func setupTableView() {
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self

        self.tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.tableView.isOpaque = true

        self.view.addSubview(self.tableView)
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "CellIdentifier")

        let frame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 30, height: 30)

        if let view = self.myView, let btn = self.toggleBtn {
            cell.addSubview(view)
            cell.addSubview(btn)
        } else {
            let myView = UIView(frame: frame)
            myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
            myView.isHidden = true

            cell.addSubview(myView)

            let toggleBtn = ToggleButton(frame: frame)
            toggleBtn.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
            toggleBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(onPress), for: .touchUpInside)
            toggleBtn.connectedView = myView

            cell.addSubview(toggleBtn)
        }

        return cell
    }

    @objc func onPress(_ sender: Any) {
        if let button = sender as? ToggleButton {
            button.onPress()
        }
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The concept of `UITableViewCell` is made to be very independent each other.

So the only thing you can do it having a bool flag in your ViewController, then you init your 3 cells with this flags.

And finally each time the button is pressed you toggle the flag en reload your tableView.